# ADO Asynchronous Query Timeout

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asynchronous

I'm using async ADO compenents for SQL in windows service with log4net logging. (BeginExecuteNonQuery with callback to EndExecuteNonQuery).

I tried my test store procedure first (waitfor delay 5 minutes) no problem.
I triend my real store procedure second (basic select and insert but sometimes i have to deal with around 10000 rows so it takes more than 30 sec. ) and i got timeout problem with async.

```
    sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=Main;User ID=login;Password=12345.;Asynchronous Processing=true;");

    var command = new SqlCommand();
    command.Connection = sqlConnection;
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;
    command.CommandText = "RefreshRows";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Connection.Open();
    AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(HandleCallback);
    command.BeginExecuteNonQuery(callback, command);
```

and i just got these in my callback method;

```
    SqlCommand command = (SqlCommand)result.AsyncState;
    int rowCount = command.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
    sqlConnection.Close();
```

**Edit:** Exception is standard sql timeout exception;

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

Where did i do wrong? Any help would be awesome and thanks already!

Comment: Please show what exception.tostring returns.

Comment: Just edited the main :)

Comment: Callstack as well, please. There is no obvious reason for the error so we have to digg. Investigate! Don't just look at the code.

Comment: I don't know why but i just uninstall and install the service and everything works well from now on. I'm still checking the logs and i'll update this as soon as i got the error, but weird :) anyway thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled and re-install the windows service and everything works well from now on. I'll update this as soon as i got the error again, weird :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is prior to opened connection sessions.

You are opening too much connections and closing them too slowly. Your number of sessions increasing and when .Net framework connection pool becomes full your app occasionaly starts to return you `Timeout expired` exception.

My recommendation is to use `using` statement. So the pool is automatically cleared when a fatal error occurs, such as a failover ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

```
using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(connString))
   {
      SqlCommand sCmd = new SqlCommand("select some from tbl", sc);
      sc.Open();
      SqlDataReader sdr = sCmd.ExecuteReader();
      sdr.Close();
   }
```